# In Minikube Buildroot OS wget: not an http or ftp url

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have Setup minikube in my Machine using Hyper-v in windows 10. All working fine, but when i tried to setup fannel network i execute following commannd.

```
wget http://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Oupput:-

```
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.192.133:80)
wget: not an http or ftp url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

I tried some solution like to install wget and hash -r but not working. 
Any idea or suggestion to solve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Note that the actual url your `wget` is trying to connect to is not an `http` but `https` url and the output you attached says:

```
wget: not an http or ftp url
```

which is true as `https` is neither `http` nor `ftp` url. It looks like your `wget` version supports only two mentioned protocols.

You can easily check it by issuing following commands:

```
wget -V | grep https
```

and

```
wget -V | grep ssl
```

I tried to reproduce it on a system possibly similar to the one you're using. For this purpose I created a `buildroot` `Pod` from `advancedclimatesystems/docker-buildroot` image:

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 buildroot --image=advancedclimatesystems/docker-buildroot --command sleep 3600
```

and I attached to it by:

```
kubectl exec -ti buildroot /bin/sh
```

Once there, I tested out your `wget` command and it was successful. It's output in my system looks like this (note the `301` redirection to `https` url):

```
root@buildroot:~/buildroot# wget http://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
--2019-12-31 16:04:27--  http://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.0.133, 151.101.64.133, 151.101.128.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.0.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml [following]
--2019-12-31 16:04:27--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.0.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14416 (14K) [text/plain]
Saving to: 'kube-flannel.yml'

kube-flannel.yml                                     100%[=====================================================================================================================>]  14.08K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-12-31 16:04:27 (53.3 MB/s) - 'kube-flannel.yml' saved [14416/14416]
```

As you can see it has built-in `ssl` and `https` support:

```
root@buildroot:~/buildroot# wget -V | grep ssl  
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/openssl 
    -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lpcre -luuid -lidn2 -lssl -lcrypto -lpsl 
    ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a

root@buildroot:~/buildroot# wget -V | grep https
-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls
```